# PHP Site Management Authentication Page

Tags: php, authentication

I have created a management page for my php site. I have a management page that I created that I would like to secure (allow only me to access).

What is the easiest way to secure this page without creating a full fledged login system? This feels like overkill, and I am afraid of creating security vulnerabilities. I have no other needs for a login system for the rest of the site.

Any recommendations or ideas from other people that have done stuff like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the easiest way creating a secure area for a single user with "Htaccess".

Example:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htaccess/ht/hthtaccess.htm

But this is not PHP or Mysql - but Apache.

Comment: I originally decided against this because I figured there wasn't something similar for lighttpd (which is what I am using). It looks like there is, so I might end up using this.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer, as it was the simplest to implement, and does everything I need. Thanks, there were lots of great answers - is this the normal protocol, give the answer to what you end up doing?

Comment: @xur17 you should accept the answer which was the most helpful for your needs. You did ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you ask for the easiest way,

You could just use your IP for comparing:

```
$myIP="your-ip-here";

if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']!=$myIP){exit();}
```

And maybe you could also do a little get param comparing too:

```
$myIP="your-ip-here";
$myGetParamPass="password";

if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']!=$myIP || $_GET['pass']!==$myGetParamPass){exit();}
```

And then access the page with YOUR IP address and with this link:

```
www.site.com/page.php?pass=password
```

But the method above will be no good if you're on a dynamic IP, which changes frequently.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way I can imagine is

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
      if($_POST['pw'] == "somepassword"){
        $_SESSION['LOGIN'] = true;
      }
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['LOGIN'])){
      //your page
    }else{ ?>
      <form method="post" action=""> <p>Password:</p>
        <input name="pw" type="password" />
        <input name="send" value="send" type="submit" />
      </form>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a cookie(use only once setcookie ("admin", "i'm admin", time() + $temps); or create it manually ) and use the following code in every webpage:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['admin'])) { 
      //Do something 
} 
else { die(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is the:

```
<?
  session_start();
  $user = 'YOUR_USERNAME';
  $password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';
  if($_POST['user'] == $user  && $_POST['password'] == $password){
      $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
  }else{
       $_SESSION['logged'] = false;
   }

  if($_SESSION['logged']){
      echo "Logged in"
  }else{
      echo "Acces denied";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: ScreenShot of the thing working]

```
<?php
$realm = 'Restricted area';

//user => password
$users = array('Username123123' => 'Password1112313', 'Guest' => 'guest');

if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm.
           '",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');

    die('<h1>HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized</h1>');
}

// analyze the PHP_AUTH_DIGEST variable
if (!($data = http_digest_parse($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) ||
    !isset($users[$data['username']]))
    die('<h1>Wrong Credentials!</h1>');


// generate the valid response
$A1 = md5($data['username'] . ':' . $realm . ':' . $users[$data['username']]);
$A2 = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].':'.$data['uri']);
$valid_response = md5($A1.':'.$data['nonce'].':'.$data['nc'].':'.$data['cnonce'].':'.$data['qop'].':'.$A2);

if ($data['response'] != $valid_response)
    die('<h1>Wrong Credentials!!</h1>');

echo 'Your are logged in as: ' . $data['username'] . '<hr />';


// function to parse the http auth header
function http_digest_parse($txt)
{
    // protect against missing data
    $needed_parts = array('nonce'=>1, 'nc'=>1, 'cnonce'=>1, 'qop'=>1, 'username'=>1, 'uri'=>1, 'response'=>1);
    $data = array();
    $keys = implode('|', array_keys($needed_parts));

    preg_match_all('@(' . $keys . ')=(?:([\'"])([^\2]+?)\2|([^\s,]+))@', $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        $data[$m[1]] = $m[3] ? $m[3] : $m[4];
        unset($needed_parts[$m[1]]);
    }

    return $needed_parts ? false : $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please mention the source. Even the manual requires attribution.